# Convert long to wide with variable number of columns

Tags: r, tidyr

Given the following data in long form, I would like to create a wide dataset with one row for each *srdr_id*, and a separate column for each *arm_name* as below.

Desired output:

```
srdr_id c1  c2 c3
174212  TAU MI MI
172612  TAU MI
```

I've tried `tidyr::spread` without success.

```
   dat <- structure(list(srdr_id = c("174212", "174212", "174212", "172612", 
    "172612"), arm_name = c("TAU", "MI", "MI", "TAU", "MI")), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Following the first suggestion, I tried:

```
dat %>%  group_by(srdr_id) %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% spread(srdr_id, arm_name)
```

Resulting in:

```
m  172612 174212
1  TAU    TAU
2  MI     MI
3  NA     MI
```

I would like the transposed version.

Comment: Create a sequence column for duplicates and then do the `spread` `dat %>% group_by(srdr_id) %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%  spread(srdr_id, arm_name)`

Comment: If you want it transposed, then transpose it: `t(dat %>%  group_by(srdr_id) %>% mutate(srdr_ids = row_number()) %>% spread(srdr_id, arm_name))`

Comment: @M-M Transposing a `data.frame` with `t` coerces it into a `matrix`, which might not be desired. Also, the `colnames` would not be formatted correctly.

Comment: @avid_useR correct. isn't it possible to convert it back to a dataframe?

Comment: @M-M Yes, but that's some extra steps to convert to `data.frame` and the first row to `colname`, which is not as trivial as simply using `t`.

Comment: @avid_useR I am not arguing that your solution is much more straightforward and efficient. My point is that transposing is an option considering akrun's comment, while not worthy of posting an answer.

Comment: @M-M I'm not questioning the correctness of your suggestion either. I'm just stating the fact that it is not as trivial as simply wrapping a `t`, because you have to convert it to `data.frame`. For those who doesn't know that `t` coerces a `data.frame` to a `matrix`, this is useful information that warrants commenting.

Comment: @avid_useR of course. I was just articulating myself. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change @akrun's suggestion by `spread`ing `id` and `arm_name`, as `id` is the "key" and `arm_name` the "value":

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(srdr_id) %>% 
  mutate(id = paste0("c", row_number())) %>% 
  spread(id, arm_name)
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   srdr_id [2]
  srdr_id c1    c2    c3   
  <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 172612  TAU   MI    <NA> 
2 174212  TAU   MI    MI
```